# Multiple exactly the same forms

Tags: c#, winforms, repeat

I have multiple forms who look exactly the same (invoice, priceoffer, order,...) Now I created the first form. But after thinking about this, all the other forms will look exactly the same.

Is there a technique, or some other way that prevents me of creating all the forms over and over again?

Comment: You could use the same ASPX page with a querystring parameter that defines the form type.

Comment: What diference will the forms have? Why not use diferent instance of the same form?

Comment: @bukko The question is tagged `winforms`, not `asp.net`.

Comment: Thanks @Maarten - switching between questions too quickly... :s

Comment: You can inherit a base form.

Comment: yes it is called visual inheriance and the good news is that c# fully supports it but the bad news is that visual studio has poor support for it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the answers. Just what i need. Ill check out all the suggestions !

Answer (score 3):

Just create a single form class that you'd call `OrderForm` or something like that

```
public class OrderForm : Form {

}
```

Then use this to create all your controls on it, and create an instance of this class every time you need to show it to a user. Best part of  this is if one of your forms changes (let's say invoice) you could just inherit from your class and only change the part that is different:

```
public class InvoiceForm : OrderForm {

}
```

And then just create an instance of `InvoiceForm` when you need that.

### EDIT answering OPs question in the comment.

Let's say you create a bunch of controls in the constructor of `OrderForm` :

```
public class OrderForm : Form {
    public OrderForm {
         var button = new Button() { ... };
         var label = new Label () { ... };
         this.Controls.Add(button);
         this.Controls.Add(label);
    }
}
```

Now if you'd create an instance of OrderForm, these controls would be added to the form, no matter how many instances you'd create of these:

```
//each of these instances have the same controls
var form1 = new OrderForm();
var form2 = new OrderForm();
var form3 = new OrderForm();
```

Now if you'd define a subclass of `OrderForm` namely `InvoiceForm`, you'd be able to use the same form controls as `OrderForm`, with some changes to it:

```
public class InvoiceForm : OrderForm {
    public InvoiceForm() : base(){ // : base() executes the constructor of the superclass
        //all controls in the `OrderForm` class are added because we called base().
        var invoiceControl = new Label() { ... };
        this.Controls.Add(invoiceControl);

        //now in total your form will count 4 controls
    }
}
```

Now you can just create an instance of `InvoiceControl` to get the changed form.

```
//first 2 forms have 3 controls, last 2 forms have 4 controls.
var form1 = new OrderForm();
var form2 = new OrderForm();
var form3 = new InvoiceForm();
var form4 = new InvoiceForm();
```

Comment: And in the example of the invoiceform. When i create an invoiceform that inherets from orderform, do i have to put the controls on it, or will those be automaticly placed on the form?

Answer (score 2):

Create a [UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388333/how-to-use-usercontrol-in-window-forms-programming-c-sharp), and use it in multiple forms.

Comment: Isn't inheritance better for this?

Comment: Could be, depends on the differences between the forms. The OP only mentions that the forms **look** the same. Maybe the data/event-handling is different between forms.

Comment: (Maybe a noob doubt) Even then, if the whole form have the same controls, isn't it better to have it inherit them from a control with no code that to add a single control that fills the full form?

Comment: Yes, the forms will look exactly the same. Only difference is the save button obviously. When its an invoice, the save will be in the invoicetable, a priceoffer will be saved into the priceoffertable, etc..

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start with Visual inheritance.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx1155fz(v=vs.110).aspx

But as GuidoG say above you could have some strange behavior in Visual Studio and in the designer.

You could handle the different save button behavior by making the click handler calling an other overridable Sub and then override this Sub in the inherited Form (instead of coding your saving process directly in the event handler as most people do:-)).

**Exemple**

```
public class BaseForm
{

    private void SaveButton_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        OnSaveButtonClick();
    }


    protected virtual void OnSaveButtonClick()
    {
    //Saving process for base form
    }
}

public class InheritedForm : BaseForm
{


    protected override void OnSaveButtonClick()
    {
    //Saving process for inherited form
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that further modification in the "base" form would also apply to the inherited one without a word. This could be an issue if you are not well organized. Sometimes it's better to do a good old copy/paste.

Comment: So ive did some testing with this, and it looks like i can't override events of the base form. They both will execute. This means i have to delete the save button to call my "orderPresenter.saveOrder() method in the buttonclick event ? My logic is splitted out of the forms. I only call methods in the events.

Comment: I have added an exemple in my answer. By the way you can't delete a "base" control in the inherited form (with the designer) but you can make it invisible.

Comment: Im not that home with VB, but I assume you use the "virtual" in the base class and then "override" in the sub class ?

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen the C# tag (shame on me I code with VB.NET I know...). You are right with virtual and override keyword for C#.